# Gravitational potential and Bessel functions

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, potential, gauss-law, coulombs-law

In electromagnetism, we can solve Laplace and Poisson equation using Bessel functions. But my question is why don't we use Bessel functions to solve these equations for gravitational potential?

Comment: Perhaps you can be a bit more specific about where in electromagnetism you would be using Bessel functions, then it is easier to discuss analogies to Newtonian gravity and/or why they are not relevant in the given example.

Comment: FWIW, Bessel functions arise in the solution of Kepler's equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation

Answer (score 1):

Spherical Bessel functions "naturally" arise as solutions of the Helmholtz equation ($\nabla^2 \phi + k^2 \phi = 0$).  This equation often arises as the spatial part of a solution to the wave equation:
$$
\nabla^2 \phi - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = 0.
$$
Assuming that $\phi$ is of the form $\phi(\vec{r}, t) = \tilde{\phi}(\vec{r}) e^{i \omega t}$ then means that $\tilde{\phi}$ obeys the Helmholtz equation, with $k = \omega/c$.

So why doesn't this ever arise in the case of gravity?  Honestly, I think the answer is that unlike electrodynamics, Newton's laws of gravity don't have a simple time-dependent version where the potential obeys the wave equation.  The full time-dependent generalization of Newtonian gravity is general relativity.  And while (in some limits) the fields of general relativity can be thought of as obeying the wave equation and/or the Helmholtz equation, these aren't situations in which it's always immediately obvious how to identify the gravitational potential.

Comment: (+1) One way to phrase why a field that can be easily identified with the gravitational potential doesn't obey a wave equation is that the gravitational potential does not correspond to one of the two tensor-like propagating degrees of freedom in GR. Strictly speaking, even in electromagnetism the same thing is true... the scalar potential doesn't obey a wave equation in a physical gauge like Coulomb gauge where the propagating degrees of freedom are manifest.

Comment: @Andrew: Good points all. But I was really hoping to avoid mentioning gauge transformations in my answer. :)

Comment: Fair enough ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There simply has not appeared a situation whereby a gravitational system had produced cylindrical symmetry. Unlike electromagnetism that has like and unlike charges, being able to be held stably in a line, in gravity there is only attraction, so that even if you could align stuff linearly, their mutual attraction would destroy that symmetry, collapsing them into a point.

Spherical Bessel functions might be useful for modelling an extended spherically distributed mass. However, again, the lack of repulsion, and the weakness of gravity (such that we always have to deal with planet sized objects before we care about their gravitational pull), means that we mostly only need the long distance monopole term.

Comment: Nitpick:  the higher-order terms in the gravitational potential still satisfy Laplace's equations ($\nabla^2 \phi = 0$) and so don't "naturally" involve spherical Bessel functions;  they're generally written in terms of powers of $r$ and spherical harmonics instead.